Can packages rebind keys globally?
I observe a strange behavior in "my" emacs.
For some reason the <next> (aka pgdn) key and the <prior> (aka pgup) key are bound to (pager-page-up) and (pager-page-down), respectively.
I just noticed it due to strange behaviour while scrolling in visual line mode.  However, I have never made any change in this direction in my configuration file.
Could a package that I installed with use-package in my configuration file make such changes to global key bindings?  How could I figure out effectively where this strange rebinding comes from?

Yes. That violates Emacs-Lisp coding conventions, but nothing other than convention prevents a package from creating or changing global key bindings.

To figure out what package (or whatever else) might be doing something, bisect your init file.  You can do that using command comment-region to comment and uncomment (with C-u prefix key) 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16, etc. of your init file (or any code/package it loads), to find the culprit. Bisecting this way is a binary search, so it's very performant, and it doesn't require a lot of thinking/analysis to locate the problem.
